# HTML radio buttons and Servlet

Tags: html, forms, servlets, input

I want to display a webpage[index page] with 3 choices for the selection of the cars. Cars could be selected by radio buttons or TextBox.

When a particular cars is selected, the servlet should response to the client showing users selection. Also, the servlet should calculate price of the selected car. But for now, I am not getting into prices, just the display of user’s selection back on his browser.

I am getting error type Status report
message /carShop/tish.com.CarServlet2
description The requested resource (/carShop/tish.com.CarServlet2) is not available.
What could be wrong:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<TITLE> Welcome to CarShop </TITLE> 
</HEAD> 

<BODY> 

<FORM Action = "tish.com.CarServlet2"  METHOD=POST> 

<BR>Select a Type of Car:<BR> 


Brand <INPUT TYPE=text NAME="Brand" > <br>

Year <INPUT TYPE=text NAME="Year" > <br> 

<input type="checkbox" name="car" value="honda">Honda<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="car" value="nissan">Nissan<br>

<INPUT TYPE= SUBMIT NAME= "Submit " Value = "Submit the Selection">
<br>
<INPUT TYPE= RESET NAME = "RESET" Value = "Reset">


</FORM> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Servlet:-

```
package tish.com;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class CarServlet2 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("Testing my Car Sevlet");
        //System.out.println(arg0.getInitParameter("Year"));
        //config =arg0;


                String [] car = req.getParameterValues("car");

                PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();

            resp.setContentType("text/html");
            writer.print("<html> <body>");
            writer.print("<hl> Your choice is </hl>");

            for (String s: car)
            {

                writer.print("<l1>" + s+ "/l1>");


            }
            writer.print("</body></html> ");
            }   


    }
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>Welcome.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CarServlet2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CarServlet2</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CarServlet2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>tish.com.CarServlet2</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

</web-app>
```

file directory setup:

carShop/tish/com.CarServlet2

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the web server logs. That should give you some indication.

Answer (score 1):

You mapped your servlet to the URL pattern `/CarServlet2`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CarServlet2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CarServlet2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So it is mapped to the absolute URL `/carShop/CarServlet2` (since `/carShop` is the context path of your webapp).

In your servlet though, you use the relative URL `tish.com.CarServlet2`, resolving to the abswolute URL `/carShop/tish.com.CarServlet2`, which is obviously not the URL the servlet is mapped to. You should use the relative URL `CarServlet2` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your .html page, see the action you given. Just make it the name . I think after you did that, It will be okay.. i.e action="./CarServlet2" not action="tish.com.CarServlet2".